# Möbius function for posets and primes

Tags: combinatorics

> Let the Möbius function $\mu_P : P \times P \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ for a poset $P$ be defined as $$\mu_P(x,y) = \begin{cases} 0 & x \not\leq y \\ 1 & x = y \\ - \sum\limits_{x \leq z < y}\mu_P(x,z) & x \leq y \end{cases} $$
>   Let further $P_n$ be the set of divisors of $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $P_n$ being ordered by the divisibility relation.
>
> Show that $\mu_{P_n}(1,n) = (-1)^m$ if $n = p_1 \cdots p_m$  with $p_1,\cdots,p_m$ being pairwise different primes.

I am looking for a pure combinatorial proof without using other definitions of the Möbius function.

I thought about the relation of n being a product of different primes and the divisors of n, but don't really know how to start. Can you tell me how this can be shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us write $\mu(n) = \mu_{P_{n}}(1, n)$.

Using only the definition, prove that $\mu$ is multiplicative, that is,
$$
\mu(xy) = \mu(x) \mu(y)
$$
if $\gcd(x, y) = 1$.

Then show that $\mu(p) = -1$ if $p$ is prime.

This is all you need. But you may also want to prove that $\mu(p^{n}) = 0$ if $p$ is a prime, and $n > 1$. This gives a general formula (assuming factorization) for the Moebius function.

---

Try it out yourself, but you can read some of the details [on p. 13 here](http://science.unitn.it/~caranti/Didattica/CFCS/2008-09/Notes/FFSC.pdf).

---

In response to the comment below by OP. When the order relation $P$ is divisibility, and $x \ne 1$, we have
$$
\mu_{P} (1, x) = - \sum_{z \mid x, z \ne x} \mu_{P}(1, z),
$$
so that if we write $\mu(x) = \mu_{P} (1, x)$ we have
$$
\sum_{z \mid x} \mu(z) = 0
$$
for $x \ne 1$, as in [the reference above](http://science.unitn.it/~caranti/Didattica/CFCS/2008-09/Notes/FFSC.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I can see why the assumption can be followed from those two conditions. Showing that $\mu(p) = -1$ if $p$ is a prime is trivial. I have a problem showing that $\mu$ is multiplicative. It is obvious why this applies (when e.g. considering the Hasse diagram of $P_n$), but how do I show that in a formal way? I tried to use the paper you mentioned, but couldn't transfer it to this particular definition. Can you please give me a hint?

Comment: @muffel, I have edited my answer to provide the requested details.

Comment: Thank you for the addition! The first part is clear, so $\mu_{P}(x) = - \sum\limits_{z \mid x, z \neq x} \mu_{P}(x)$. But how do you follow that $\mu_P(x) = 0$ for $x \neq 1$? $\mu(2) = -\mu(1) = - \mu_P(1,1) = -1 \neq 0$?

Comment: @muffel, where did I say that???

Comment: I read your edit again, sorry, I just misunderstood it. Nevertheless you say "[...] if we write $\mu(x) = \mu_P(1,x)$ we have $\sum\limits_{z\mid x} \mu(z) = 0$". I tried it and it worked, but why is that sum always zero for $x \neq 1$? I tried to follow the paper you mentioned, but have problems understanding the syntax. According to your answer "(n,m) = 1" might mean "$gcd(n,m) = 1$", right? "$d\mid nm$" means for sure "$d$ divides $nm$", but what about "$e,e\mid n$"?

Comment: @muffel, yes, $(n,m)$ is an old-fashioned notation for $\gcd(n,m)$ (I'm ancient), whereas $d \mid nm$ is the standard notation for divisibility. Then $\sum_{e, e\mid n}$ means *sum over all $e$ dividing $n$*.

Comment: @muffel, as to the sum being zero, it is **exactly the same sum you have in your post**, that is, $\mu_P(1,y) = - \sum\limits_{x \leq z < y}\mu_P(1,z)$ for $1 < y$, so I cannot understand what is your problem with it. (Of course $\le$ has to be replaced with divisibility here.)